# Links to previous/next month archives

Tags: php, archive-template

On the month archive page (using the date.php template), how can I add links for the previous month and next month? For example, viewing January 2022 (/2022/01), I'd like a link to December 2021 (/2021/12) and a link to February 2022 (/2022/02).

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I started down the path of finding the current archive's date, and then subtracting a month from it to get the previous month, and then use get_month_link() to get the link... but I wasn't sure if that was the best way so I haven't fully pursued it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! It's not pretty but it's functioning.

```
$Y = get_the_time( 'Y' );
$M = get_the_time( 'm' );

$earlier_post = get_posts( [
    'date_query' => [
        'before' => [
            'year'  => $Y,
            'month' => $M,
            'day'   => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'orderby'             => 'date',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
] );

$prev_label = get_the_time( 'F', $earlier_post[0] ) . ' ' . get_the_time( 'Y', $earlier_post[0] );

if ( ! empty( $earlier_post ) ) {
    $previous_month_link = home_url( get_the_time( 'Y', $earlier_post[0] ) . '/' . zeroise( get_the_time( 'm', $earlier_post[0] ), 2 ) );
    echo '<div class="nav-prev"><a href="' . $previous_month_link . '"><span class="nav-title">' . $prev_label . '</span></a></div>';
}

$next_post = get_posts( [
    'date_query' => [
        'after' => [
            'year'  => $Y,
            'month' => $M,
            'day'   => date( 't', mktime( 23, 59, 59, $M, 1, $Y ) ),
        ],
    ],
    'orderby'             => 'date',
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
] );

$next_label = get_the_time( 'F', $next_post[0] ) . ' ' . get_the_time( 'Y', $next_post[0] );

if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ) {
    $next_month_link = home_url( get_the_time( 'Y', $next_post[0] ) . '/' . zeroise( get_the_time( 'm', $next_post[0] ), 2 ) );
    echo '<div class="nav-next"><a href="' . $next_month_link . '"><span class="nav-title">' . $next_label . '</span></a></div>';
}
```